# laravel 5.5 email-verification with josiasmontag package FatalThrowableError

Tags: laravel-5.5

I have installed laravel 5.5 and implementing 
I have pulled in composer require josiasmontag/laravel-email-verification and everything seems to ok but when a user register or when I click the register I get

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to 
Lunaweb\EmailVerification\EmailVerification::createToken() must be an 
instance of Lunaweb\EmailVerification\Contracts\CanVerifyEmail, 
instance of App\User given, called in 
/Users/sam/site/vendor/josiasmontag/laravel-email-
verification/src/EmailVerification.php on line 127
```

here is the link to the parkage
https://github.com/josiasmontag/laravel-email-verification
I am not really good at php, if anyone has experience with it, please help

Comment: Which argument were you passed? Add some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ahh, I forgot to implements CanVerifyEmailContract in the User model.
now it works fine.